# ResNeXt50 CUDA OutOfMemoryError

Tags: pytorch

when I'm training ResNeXt50 using my dataset,in 'train' process,came out an error:

> torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate
> 196.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 7.14 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 7.15 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If
> reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb
> to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and
> PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

I added 'del' and torch.cuda.empty_cache() after every train step,but the error occurred before the train step finish,so it is not useful for me

Comment: What is your `batch_size`? Maybe try with a smaller `batch_size`.

Comment: I changed the batch size from 64 to 32, it worked. Is smaller batch size will reduce the final accuracy?

Comment: It can go both ways, you can observe either increment or decrement in accuracy. You need to tune your hyperparameters accordingly to get the optimum result.